# How to create a EJB "session scoped" singleton bean?

Tags: glassfish, singleton, ejb, stateful

What is best practices to implement a *"session scoped singleton"*?

I need a "session-scoped singleton bean" that I can "inject/insert" into other `@Stateful` beans.

I learned that simply injecting a `@Stateful` bean does not help because the other beans each got a different instance of my "not-so-realy-singleton-bean". Annotating as `@Singleton` does not help either because I do not want an **application**-scoped singleton but a **session**-scoped singleton.

Comment: Why aren't you satisfied with the SessionScoped annotation? Can you show a concrete example?

Comment: I have theese stateful session beans that impement different remote interfaces IX and IY. These beans are used by **different** remote clients: ClientA uses interface IX only while ClientB uses interface IX and IY - **interface IY may not be exposed** to ClientA. The beans that implement IX and IY on the server need to **share** another bean. With _"share"_ I mean the same instance - and I don't know how to allocate/reference/inject/whatsoever this shared instance.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this out @cssdata? Perhaps creating your own context with CDI could help?